# How can I filter the inner select?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a postgresql query, what is very fast.

```
SELECT a.name1,
       a.name2,
       b.*
FROM 
( SELECT name1, name2 FROM dummy1
   WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8') ) a
JOIN dummy2 b
       ON b.a_id=a.id where ...;
```

How shall I declare/construct the JPQL query from this?

Comment: Is there a reason for using a subselect? Why not `SELECT ... FROM dummy1 a JOIN dummy2 ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE a.id in ('1', ..., '8');`? Then it's probably a lot easier to do that in JPQL than with subselects.

Comment: @yasd: Because the query is optimized in this way.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see why using a subselect optimizes a query - maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: JPQL doesn't allow SUBquery as the candidate of the query. So either rearrange as suggested or use native queries and lose database independence

Comment: @yasd: The original query is terminating under 2 secs approximately. But that query what are you suggesting is running more time (7secs). Unfortunatelly! How can I achieve the original query in JPQL? Can you help me, pls?

Comment: @Neil Stockton: Does not have any other solution?